# after click to submit button my page is not redirecting to another page given in form action

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I click to the submit button my page is not redirecting to the  `book_appoinment.php` page.

Here is my code. I cannot figure out what's wrong with my code.

```
<?php
include('include/config.php');
?> 
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/rd-mailform.css">

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src='js/device.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
        });

            function changebrands()
            {
                    $("#brands_ul li a").click(function(){
                        $("#brands").text($(this).text());
                    });
            }
            function changemodels()
            {
                    $("#models_ul li a").click(function(){
                        $("#models").text($(this).text());
                    });
            }
            function changeprocessors()
            {
                    $("#processors_ul li a").click(function(){
                        $("#processors").text($(this).text());
                    });
            }
            function changeyears()
            {
                    $("#years_ul li a").click(function(){
                        $("#years").text($(this).text());
                    });
            }

    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>

<body>
<div class="page">
        <section class="parallax banner01">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="prefix_4 grid_4">
                        <!-- RD Mailform -->
                        <form class="rd-mailform" method="get" action="book_appoinment.php">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>

                                            <div class = "form-group">
                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                              <button id="brands" onclick="changebrands();" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"  style = "height:50px; width:112%; text-align:left; font-size:large; color:gray;">
                                              Brand
                                              </button>
                                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="brands_ul" aria-labelledby="brand_dropdown" style = "width:112%;">
                                              <?php
                                                $rs_brand = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT l_brand FROM my_web_data_temp");

                                                if(mysql_num_rows($rs_brand) > 0)
                                                {
                                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_brand))
                                                    {?>
                                                        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row['l_brand'];?></a></li>
                                                    <?php
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                              </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>   

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class = "form-group">
                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                              <button id="models" onclick="changemodels();" name = "model"aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"  style = "height:50px; width:112%; text-align:left; font-size:large; color:gray;">
                                                Model

                                              </button>
                                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="models_ul" aria-labelledby="model_dropdown" style = "width:112%;">
                                                <?php
                                                $rs_model = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT l_model FROM my_web_data_temp");

                                                if(mysql_num_rows($rs_model) > 0)
                                                {
                                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_model))
                                                    {?>
                                                        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row['l_model'];?></a></li>
                                                    <?php
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                              </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class = "form-group">
                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                              <button id="processors" onclick="changeprocessors();" name = "processor" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"  style = "height:50px; width:112%; text-align:left; font-size:large; color:gray;">
                                                Processor

                                              </button>
                                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="processors_ul" aria-labelledby="model_dropdown" style = "width:112%;">
                                                <?php
                                                $rs_processor = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT l_processor FROM my_web_data_temp");

                                                if(mysql_num_rows($rs_processor) > 0)
                                                {
                                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_processor))
                                                    {?>
                                                        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row['l_processor'];?></a></li>
                                                    <?php
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ?>

                                              </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class = "form-group">
                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                              <button id="years" onclick="changeyears();" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" style = "height:50px; width:112%; text-align:left; font-size:large; color:gray;">
                                                year

                                              </button>
                                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="years_ul" aria-labelledby="year_dropdown" style = "width:112%";>

                                                <?php
                                                $year = date("Y");
                                                for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++)
                                                {?>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><?PHP echo $year; ?></a></li>
                                                    <?php $year= $year-1;?>
                                                <?php
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                              </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class = "form-group">
                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                              <button id="condition"  aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" style = "height:50px; width:112%; text-align:left; color:gray;">
                                                No physical damage - Working condition

                                              </button>

                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>                   

                                </table>

                                <div class = "form-group">
                                    <div>                                       
                                        <input type="submit"
                                          name="submit"
                                          class="btn btn-default" 
                                          value="EVALUATE YOUR DEVICE NOW" 
                                          style="background-color:lawngreen; width:100%; height:50px;">                                 
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>


</div>


<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my config file:

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set ("Asia/Calcutta");

    define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://192.168.43.23/site/'); 
    define('ENABLE_SSL', false);

    define('SITE_URL', 'http://192.168.43.23/site/');   
    define('SITE_URL_ADMIN', SITE_URL.'admin/');
    define('SITE_CSS', SITE_URL.'css/');
    define('DIR_WS_IMAGES', SITE_URL.'images/');
    define('DIR_WS_INCLUDES', SITE_URL.'include/');
    define('SITE_JS', SITE_URL.'js/');

    define('DIR_FS','C:/xampp/htdocs/site/');
    define('DIR_FS_ADMINCP',DIR_FS.'admin/');
    define('DIR_FS_IMG', DIR_FS.'images/');
    define('DIR_FS_INCLUDES',DIR_FS.'include/');
    define('DIR_FS_SUPPLIER_IMAGE',DIR_FS_SUPPLIER.'images/');
    define('DIR_WS_TEMPLATES', DIR_FS.'templates/');
    define('DIR_WS_TEMPLATES_ADMIN_CP', DIR_WS_TEMPLATES.'admin/');
    define('DIR_WS_CONTENT', DIR_WS_TEMPLATES.'content/');
    define('DIR_WS_CONTENT_ADMINCP', DIR_WS_TEMPLATES_ADMIN_CP.'content/');

    define('RACKS_SEQ', 'RACKS_SEQ');
    define('PROD_DOM_SEQ', 'PROD_DOM_SEQ');
    define('PROD_INT_SEQ', 'PROD_INT_SEQ');

    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root');
    define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', 'swetav');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'my_website');
    define('USE_PCONNECT', 'false');
    define('STORE_SESSIONS', 'mysql');
    define('RECORDS_PER_PAGE',5);

/////////////////////// Tables /////////////////////////
    define(TAB_STATE_MASTER,"table_name");  
    require_once(DIR_FS_INCLUDES.'function/function.php');
    $db_link = re_db_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_SERVER_USERNAME,DB_SERVER_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
    define('DB_LINK', $db_link);
?>
```

my function:

```
function re_db_connect($server = DB_SERVER, $username = DB_SERVER_USERNAME, $password = DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, $database = DB_DATABASE, $link = 'db_link') 
{
    global $$link;

    if (USE_PCONNECT == 'true') {
      $$link = mysql_pconnect($server, $username, $password);
    } else {
      $$link = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
    }

    if ($$link) mysql_select_db($database);

    return $$link;
}
```

Comment: <button id="models" onclick="changemodels();" name = "model" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"  style = "height:50px; width:112%; text-align:left; font-size:large; color:gray;">
                                                Model

                                              </button>

Comment: replace this line

Comment: replacing this line is not working  :(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/umm4wo4u/ check this link. your code is working.

Comment: check your database connection and query execution

Comment: i already checked my database and queries, i am getting values from my database

Comment: remove php code and submit form

Comment: @Bilal Ahmed did you edit something?

Comment: no. diagnose the error. remove php code and submit form.. then tell me what happen

Comment: but i need loop for my dropdown because i am  taking dropdown list values from my database

Comment: you try this.. if form is submit successfully then error in php code

Comment: i removed all php code but still its not working

Comment: close all files and restart server(xamp or wamp).. your code is working fine.. i have try my own server and jsfiddle.com

Comment: i did that i restarted my laptop but still not working

Comment: i tried to post whole code but i cant

Comment: finally solution is. give me a complete code with database connection code..i will create own server and try

Comment: i posted my whole code please check this and give the solution

Comment: after removing all your php code, the form submits successfully. However, none of the data is sent since you are using buttons as inputs. I recommend using an input or rather a select tag instead.